# Is an asymptotic expansion of the heat kernel known on any space of fractal dimension?

Tags: fractals, heat-equation

Is an asymptotic expansion of the heat kernel known on any space of fractal dimension?  I was able to find a 2012 paper saying it was not ([https://www.math.tugraz.at/~grabner/Publications/Physics_Review.pdf](https://www.math.tugraz.at/%7Egrabner/Publications/Physics_Review.pdf)), but I am wondering if any expansion has since been derived.  In particular, I am interested to know whether there might be any similarity to the case of heat kernel expansions on manifolds with boundaries, where terms with non-integer exponent (half-integer powers, in the case of a manifold with boundaries) appear (e.g. as mentioned in https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0306138).